# How to use sed with file path variables AND regex callbacks AND arithmetic expressions

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, text-processing

I'm having a hell of a time getting the proper syntax using `sed` with variables containing a file path, a regex callback and an arithmatic expression.  I don't know how to properly escape things.

I have a file path in a text file with a number next to it.  I want to find this line and increment the number.

```
FILE="/home/username/scripts/test.txt"
LINE="/home/username/Pictures/properties/wallpaper/span/tree.jpg"

sed -i -e "s,'$LINE' \([0-9]*\),'$LINE' $((\1+1))," $FILE
```

For example..

```
/home/username/Pictures/properties/wallpaper/span/tree.jpg 2
```

should become..

```
/home/username/Pictures/properties/wallpaper/span/tree.jpg 3
```

What is the best way to escape the "." in the file path?  How do I properly implement the `\1` callback and the arithmetic expression `$((\1+1)`?

Currently I'm getting bad token `\1+1` error.

Comment: Have you considered using `awk`? e.g. `awk -v line="$LINE" '$1==line {$2++}1' "$FILE"`

Comment: Please, don't use the `awk` or `sed` tags unless you're specifically interested in those tools. It's clear here that your primary purpose is getting this done, not using `sed` or `awk` specifically.

Comment: well `sed` is explicit in my Question title and `awk` was the sensible answer and replacement for `sed`.  I just want people to be able to find this question if they are in a similar situation to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` and arithmetic do not mix.  The right tool for jobs like this is `awk`.

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat test.txt
/nonmatching/line 1
/home/username/Pictures/properties/wallpaper/span/tree.jpg 2
/another/non/matching/line 5
```

We can increment the number of the line that you want with:

```
$ line="/home/username/Pictures/properties/wallpaper/span/tree.jpg"
$ awk -v f="$line" '$0~f {$NF++} 1' test.txt
/nonmatching/line 1
/home/username/Pictures/properties/wallpaper/span/tree.jpg 3
/another/non/matching/line 5
```

As you can see, this incremented the number on the line that matched `$line`.

One limitation is that this code, as written, will not preserve multiple blanks on lines for which the number is incremented.  If whitespace is important, we would need more definition of the input format.

#### How it works

- `-v f="$line"`

  This assigns the value of the shell variable `line` to the awk variable `f`.
- `$0~f {$NF++}`

  Here, `$0~f` is a condition.  It is true if the input line, denoted `$0`, matches the regex `f` as defined above.  If it matches, then the statement `$NF++` is executed.  This increments the last field on the line which, for your input, is the number.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Editing a file in-place with `awk`

If you have a modern GNU awk, you can edit the file in place with:

```
gawk -i inplace -v f="$line" '$0~f {$NF++} 1' test.txt
```

With other awks, use:

```
awk -v f="$line" '$0~f {$NF++} 1' test.txt > tmp.txt && mv -f tmp.txt test.txt
```

#### Creating `text.txt` if it doesn't exist

In the case that the file `test.txt` is does not contain a line matching `$line`, this version will such a line with `1` as the count:

```
gawk -i inplace -v f="$line" '$0~f {n=1; $NF++} 1; END{if(!n) print f,1>>FILENAME}' test.txt
```

This code adds a variable `n`.  If `$line` is in the file, `n` is set to `1`.  If it isn't, `n` stays at the default value of `0`.  At the `END` of the input file, the value of `n` is tested.  If `n` is still zero, the line is added.

Comment: This seems way easier for sure.  I'll use your `awk` solution.  Is `awk` standard in most installs?

Comment: Yes, `awk` is standard with Unix/Linux.  (If you are on sun/solaris, be aware that the _default_ awk is old and buggy.)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting output.  It doesn't seem to be writing to my `FILE="/path/to/file.test.text"` in `awk -v f="$line" '$0~f {$NF++} 1' $FILE`.  How does awk know I want to read and write to that file?

Comment: I have `exec &> $(pwd)/`echo ${0##*/} | cut -f 1 -d '.'`.log` at beginning of my script and for some reason `awk` copies the entire `test.txt` to `test.log` with the value incremented in `test.log` only.

Comment: @deanresin Yes, by default, both sed and awk send their output to stdout which would be captured by your `exec` statement.  I have updated the answer with info on  editing in-place.

Comment: is there a way I can append the `$LINE` if it is not already in the `$FILE`?  I tried `gawk -i inplace -v f="$LINE" '$0~f {$NF++} 1' $FILE || echo "$LINE 1" >> $FILE` but did not work.

Comment: the following worked for me `! grep -q $LINE $FILE && echo "$LINE 1" >> $FILE || gawk -i inplace -v f="$LINE" '$0~f {$NF++} 1' $FILE`

Comment: @deanresin Very good.  Also, I just added a version to the answer that uses pure awk.

Comment: nice.  I'll probably use your version after I learn more of awk.

Comment: `gawk -i inplace -v f="$line" '$0~f {n=1; $NF++} 1; END{if(!n) print f,1}' test.txt` isn't working for me.  Does the `n` not have to be explicitly initialized to zero?

Comment: @deanresin You are right!  I just fixed it.  See updated answer.